# Java Spring app + Tomcat: JVM doesn't make memory dump

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, out-of-memory, dump

in my company we develope an enterprise web application in Spring (Flex frontend) and deploy this app to our customers in Tomcat 6 in SAAS style.

Recently we are suffering from (seemingly) random OutOfMemory errors so after investigation I knew that we should inspect the memory dump of the JVM  in the moment of the error.

The JVM we use is 1.6.18 and the Tomcat version is Tomcat 7.0.23 under Windows Server 2008.

I added the parameter -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError in the Tomcat monitor panel (under Java tab) but the machines aren't producing any dump.

The full java options are set as follows on the server we are investigating:

```
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\logging.properties
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx6144m
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

As you can see the max heap size is pretty large (6 Gigs) since out app is particurarly heavy.
I added for testing reasons the jmx parameters in order to view the JVM status in real time with VisualVM, but nothig occurred while I was looking at it.

All that the stderr shows is this:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

[image: oom]
Nothing before it (except other errors that I don't know if correlated, but they are logged hours or several minutes before the OOM) and nothing after it.

It seems strange to me that it doesn't report the memory section (Java heap size, or Permgen Space).

Maybe the memory heap reserved is too big and the JVM can't write it at since it's in a critical state (OOM)? 
Maybe the JMX parameters are messing things up?

This is the VisualVM screenshot of currently running JVM:
[image: VisualVM]

**UPDATE:**

I installed on another tomcat installation (same version as the one in which the problem originated and **same java options**) the same web application modified to manually provoke an OOM by undefinitely filling an arraylist in an infinite loop.
The test proved that the java option -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError works, since a memory dump was produced after I provoked the OOM; in this case however the error was:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap space
```

following with the stack trace.
So it seems that the problem is not with my JVM args notation but with the particular kind of error I'm encountering.

Another peculiarity is that after throwing the OOM error in my test, the app continued to work in Tomcat. The OOM in my original issue on the other hand causes the stop of the Tomcat service.

Sadly without a stack trace taken a moment before it stops it looks difficult to further investigate. :(

Comment: Why don't you use jvisualVm to create a memory dump? (you can use MAT to study the leaks from the memory dump - it's free)
Or use it when you have the application deployed on tomcat and monitor the application as you close it and open it, in this way you can see if all the threads are closing or not.

Comment: @aurelius Thanks for your comment. I'm currently using VisualVM and I know that I can make dumps out of it, but what I want is a dump when the OOM strikes (the -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError options should do that I think). I tried some days ago to make a dump whit VisualVM and look at it with MAT, but with no success (I add that I don't know precisely where to look in analysing a dump, I usually look at the suspect memory leaks and Dominator Tree)

Comment: Pretty sure that you have checked on it but will say it anyway: do you have space (around 6 gb) on your disk for the heap dump?

Comment: Yes @Khanna111GauravKhanna, there is plenty of space :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `-XX:HeapDumpPath="/some/path/dump.out"` to your JVM args explicitly set the heap dump file location

Comment: Ok, next time we reebot Tomcat we will try to explicitly set the path of the dump (But this never seemed a problem to me, since on out local machines, heap dumps where created also without specifying the path).
Thanks Amir

Comment: You are right, the answer does not specify it is mandatory. In that case this answer does not solve the question.

Comment: Yes, I suspected this wasn't a path problem but I tried anyway to specify it, without success. Thanks however. I made another test described in the update of my question.

Comment: What did you specify exactly in your JVM args @frankieta?

Comment: @AmirAfghani My JVM args were the same plus the heap dump path. Specifically:
-....catalina properties...
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx6144m
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath="C:/"
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 

The program terminated as wrote the dump in my C partition.
This was the console:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to C:/\java_pid7996.hprof ...

Comment: instead of "C:/" try "C:/dump.out".  Are you sure your program has write permissions to C:??

Comment: @AmirAfghani, Yes my app has permission to write to C: because my second test app (the one designed to crash with an OOM error) just worked and wrote the .hprof dump file in the C: partition. 
I guess we will have to use some diagnostic software like New Relic or similar to help us understand what's happening here. Thanks

PS: sorry for the delay in my comment response...Christmas time..